# Shared variable in a class that can be use in a constructor

Tags: javascript, oop

What is the best way to declare a shared variable in a class that can be used inside a constructor?

I tried using a prototype like so:

```
class Cell {

  constructor(element) {    
    this.view = document.createElement(element);
    this.value = cellSymbol.NO_MINE;
  }

  isMine() { return this.value == cellSymbol.MINE; }
  makeMine() { this.value = cellSymbol.MINE; }
  getView() { return this.view; }
  addOnClickFn(func) { this.view.onclick = func; }
  removeOnClickFn() { this.view.onclick = ''; }
  addClassStyle(style) { this.view.className = style; }
  openCell(style) {
    this.view.className = style;
    this.value = cellSymbol.OPEN_CELL;
  }
}

Cell.prototype.cellSymbol = Object.freeze({
      NO_MINE: 0,
      MINE: 9,
      OPEN_CELL: '#'
});

var cell = new Cell('td');
```

but it doesn't work. I get `cellSymbol` is undefined. I assume that class constructor is created before prototype and therefore `cellSymbol` is unknown.

I see no point putting `cellSymbol` into the class because there is no need for every instance having it's own `cellSymbol`.

Comment: What do you mean by "shared variable"? `Cell.prototype.cellSymbol` is not a variable, it's a property to be inherited by instances. Use `const cellSymbol = …;`.

Comment: I mean a variable/object that is shared between all instances that derive from `class Cell`. Something that each instance doesn't own by itself. For example, in C++ and Java, one can use static variables (weather it is an object, or a primitive).

Comment: I think even in C++ and Java, these are called attributes not variables. And I don't see why you would use a static property (`Cell.cellSymbol`) over a simple global variable (just `cellSymbol`).

Comment: Although it's for a school project, I thought not to pollute the global namespace and I would like to learn best practices in Javascript. Why would a global variable be better?

Comment: I meant not necessarily global, just outside of the `class` or any of its methods - contained in the module scope. Who would need to use this object and how?

Comment: Another class named `Game` would create those `cells` and add them into an array. And then it would traverse that array, call out `getView()` on each element and create a separate view for `HMTL`. At first I had that `cellSymbol` in `Game` but thought maybe it's better to put it in `Cell`, because it should know about it and not `Game`.

Comment: If the other modules like `Game` should not need to know about it, a `const cellSymbol` in the module scope is the perfect place.